# How do I set a variable value in emacs org mode?

Tags: variables, emacs, org-mode

The org-mode tutorial often talks about setting the value of a variable to change the behavior of the mode. For example, in [this org-mode tutorial](http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-scheduling):

> This warning is deactivated if the task gets scheduled and you **set org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled to t**.

I have been searching for a while but it looks like knowing how to set an emacs variable value is an assumed knowledge in many tutorials.

Could someone please educate me how and where to set variables in the org-mode? Is it set in the .emacs file or in each org file? Do these questions even make sense or am I missing some important concepts?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You generally set variables in your `.emacs`. You can also use `M-x customize` to enter an interactive mode for setting preferences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because emacs.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: @Barmar: That's not a reason to close the question. Users are free to choose which of the two sites they want o pose an Emacs question on. That's why tag `emacs` exists here. What's to be avoided is duplicate posting of the same question on both sites.

Comment: @Drew Well, I don't consider simple customization like this to be "programming". I just didn't go into that level of detail in my comment.

Comment: @Barmar: Questions about Emacs (including customizing it) are certainly on topic here. StackOverflow is "*Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers*". And "*if your question generally covers a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development then you’re in the right place to ask your question!* (Not to mention that this question about setting a variable is also a programming question, however basic.)

Comment: @Drew I admit it's a fuzzy distinction, like when a question about `.profile` is appropriate for SO versus Unix.SE. Even though `.profile` is technically a program, if you're just talking about trivial variable assignments I wouldn't consider it on-topic here.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar and Drew for spending time on this topic. I'd like to defend my question by saying that it might be simple for people who knew how to do it, but it is not obvious for me in this case. Also given that emacs configuration settings are not super user-friendly, I hope the question could be helpful for other in similar situation, especially new emacs users.  I couldn't think of any other places where this question can be answered from emacs experts. Please kindly keep the question alive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Customize**

If you want some help about a variable, you can use `C-h v` then Emacs will ask you the variable name.

There if you enter `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled` you will see a buffer with the variable
description. At the end you will see a clickable **customize**. Click it and you will see an interactive buffer from which you can change variable value (saved in your `.emacs` file).

*Note:* you can directly use `M-x customize-option` + variable name

**With `setq` lisp function:**

Another way is to directly use this:

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled t)
```

- in your `.emacs` file or
- in the `*scratch*` buffer, then `M-x eval-buffer`

(Your modification is immediate but not saved.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in org files like this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
  (setq org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled t)
#+END_SRC
```

Then if you put point inside the block (between the BEGIN and END) and hit C-c C-c, the elisp will be evaluated.  That runs the little elisp snippet.  The variable will be changed for the rest of your emacs session but the change will not be permanent unless you add the snippet to your init.el or other initialization file.

I find that to be a nice way to try things out.  I have also set up my init.el to open some org files and interpret all the elisp in them, e.g., init.org, so if I want to make a permanent change to my configuration I add the snippet to init.org, C-c C-c to run it during the current session, and then it also runs in any future session.  Search for "Emacs Literate Configuration" to get started with that method.